# Renamed SSIS Package and then Was Suddenly Deleted; Can I Restore Somehow?

Tags: ssis

Spent 2 days configuring an SSIS package.  Just got everything configured the way it needed to be.  Noticed the package didn't have a good name so I renamed it and now is deleted!!!

Is there any way to restore this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's deleted from file system then there is no other way than using data recovery software. You can easily find one online (open source/trial version).

If you have deployed package before deletion then you can recover it from MSDB.

[Extracting SSIS package definition from MSDB](http://sqlconcept.com/2011/12/06/extracting-ssis-package-definition-from-msdb/)

[export an SSIS package  to a .dtsx file](http://timlaqua.com/2008/06/exporting-ssis-packages-stored-on-the-server-msdb-to-dtsx-xml/)

[SSIS Package Extract from MSDB](http://billfellows.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html)

[Copying SSIS packages deployed on SQL Server back to Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191556/copying-ssis-packages-deployed-on-sql-server-back-to-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: thanks for the response...ended up rewriting the package